# Var array to list box

Tags: c#, arrays, json, listbox

So on my last post, [C# Json - to - Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060167/c-sharp-json-to-array) I asked how to get the two values to a array. But I was given a var, how do I get those variables in a list box "main_Listbox"?

Comment: using var is a bad habit that will prevent you from knowing what any specific thing is.

Comment: @ohmusama What? No.. it really isn't.

Comment: Sure, if you are a good programmer, by all means, use it. But if you are new as in the case of above, I would never recommend using var, because he'll never figure out how to pass it into anything because all documentation will specify types, which won't even make sense because he has a "magical" var.

Comment: Good advice. Skip useful parts of a language whilst learning because they are "magic". Nothing is magic. The IDE and compiler know what a variable is implicitly typed as. You just have to type `variable.` into the IDE and intellisense kicks in. Even hovering over the variable name tells you what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Anything declared as `var` in code is **implicitly typed**. This means the following:

```
var s = "Hello World!"; // This is compiled as a string
var i = 10; // This is compiled as an integer
var list = new List<string>(); // This is compiled as a List of strings
var arr = new byte[255]; // This is compiled as a byte array.
```

Your linked post appears to show that your variable is assigned from a json serializer. This means it will be a string.

There is also another assignment in the other answer that would be a `List<User>`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically to add values of an array or any collection you can use the `foreach` statement that allows you to iterate over all the elements of a collection that implements the `IEnumerable` interface. For example:

```
foreach (var user in listOfUsers)
{
    listBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", user.id, user.pass, user.status.ToString());
}
```

Considering that `listOfUsers` is of type `List<User>` and the `User` class is like that:

```
class User
{
    public string id;
    public string pass;
    public int status;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060167/c-sharp-json-to-array/19060416#19060416) I gave you in the previous question, I have used the following with a `var`

```
var totalBonusUsers = (from user in data.users
                                   let tot = user.bonus.GetTotalBonus()
                                   select new TotalUserBonus {username = user.username, totalBonus = tot}).ToList()
                                                                                                          .OrderByDescending
                (u => u.totalBonus).ToList();
```

`var` is actually = `List<TotalUserBonus>` in this instance.

```
main_Listbox.DataSource = totalBonusUsers;
main_Listbox.DataTextField = "username";
main_Listbox.DataValueField = "totalBonus";
main_Listbox.DataBind();
```